# My computer shows up three times in my wireless client list

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

For some odd reason I decided to reset my modem router and I know for a fact that my laptop is the only one connected to my WiFi. So why does my Laptop show up three different times?

As you can see in the below list it shows up with the same MAC address and Name three times.

```
Wireless Client List

Name            IP                                      MAC
DESKTOP-5320OI3 192.xxx.x.x                             6C:71:D9:ww:yy:xx
DESKTOP-5320OI3 2607:FCC8:F2D3:7700:1126:FF6E:BAFE:41A2 6C:71:D9:ww:yy:xx
DESKTOP-5320OI3 FE80::3C56:BFCB:3D2B:7F96               6C:71:D9:ww:yy:xx
```

Comment: First entry IPv4, second and third entry IPv6 (one being link local).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PC supports the IPv4 and IPv6 protocol. As you can see in your list it's listing three different IP addresses.

The first one (192...) is an IPv4 address. The second one is a IPv6 address which looks like it's an actual internet address. One of the advantages of IPv6 is that you get a whole block of IPs and (theoretically) each device on your Networks gets a working IPv6 address.

The last address (FE80...) is also an IPv6 address but [link local](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113328-ipv6-lla.html). It won't be routed to the internet.